# Filtering on values of a relationship's property in a query before returning

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm performing a query which looks like

```
MATCH p = (n:NODEA)-[:RELA]->(s:NODEB)-[:RELB*]->(j:NODEB)
WITH *, relationships(p) AS re
RETURN *
```

I want to filter the graph to remove all instances where a `RELB` (an edge between two `NODEB`s) does not have a specific property before returning.

The query works if I bind the relationship using `[rels:RELB*]` and filter on `rels`, however I get a message saying this feature is deprecated and to use `WITH *, relationships(p)` instead. The specific message is

> This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
>   Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated. (Binding a variable length relationship pattern to a variable ('rels') is deprecated and will be unsupported in a future version. The recommended way is to bind the whole path to a variable, then extract the relationships: MATCH p = (...)-[...]-(...) WITH *, relationships(p) AS rels)

I've tried

```
MATCH p = (n:NODEA)-[:RELA]->(s:NODEB)-[:RELB*]->(j:NODEB)
WITH *, relationships(p) AS re
WHERE ANY (thing IN re WHERE thing.prop = 'value')
RETURN *
```

But it still seems to return everything the same as the first query

I've also tried list comprehension to filter the relationships

```
MATCH p = (n:NODEA)-[:RELA]->(s:NODEB)-[:RELB*]->(j:NODEB)
WITH *, [re in relationships(p) WHERE re.prop = 'value'] AS re
RETURN *
```

But I believe this approach has a few issues:

1. relationships(p) seems to be an array of arrays due to the nature of the graph
2. there are multiple types of relationships in relationships(p) (`RELA`s and `RELB`s) and I'm not sure how to take that into account

I can't really find any documentation online around how to filter on the relationships when they are returned as a list (due to the `*` in `[:RELB*]`)

I should also note that the property I need to filter `RELB` on is an array and I'll check whether it contains some value, so I don't have the option to use something like `[:RELB*{prop: 'value'}]` in the query (I just didn't include that above to not complicate the question)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are *all* `RELB` relationships in each desired path required to have that property value, or is it sufficient for just one relationship in the path to have that value? Also, is it possible for the `RELA` relationship to have that value?

Comment: Yes to the first question - all `RELB`s in the resulting path should have that property value. `RELA` doesn't even have that property, it shouldn't be filtered on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `rels` approach is deprecated (for some reason), here is a more cumbersome equivalent using `p =` and `RELATIONSHIPS(p)`:

```
MATCH p = (n:NODEA)-[:RELA]->(s:NODEB)-[:RELB*]->(j:NODEB)
WHERE ALL(thing IN RELATIONSHIPS(p)[1..] WHERE thing.prop = 'value')
RETURN *
```

By the way, if your query is taking a long time and/or running out of memory, then you may want to put a reasonable upper bound on your variable-length relationship pattern (e.g., `[:RELB*..6]`), since such a pattern's time and space complexities grow exponentially by the depth of the search.

[ORIGINAL ANSWER]

This query uses the `rels` variable to hold a list of just the `RELB` relationships:

```
MATCH (n:NODEA)-[:RELA]->(s:NODEB)-[rels:RELB*]->(j:NODEB)
WHERE ALL(thing IN rels WHERE thing.prop = 'value')
RETURN *
```

I have removed `p =` from the pattern, as `p` is not needed by this query. If you need it in your result, you can add it back (but the `rels` list will give you all of the `RELB` relationships, so you may not need `p`).

You need to use the `ALL()` function (not `ANY()`) if you want to require all `RELB` relationships to have the desired property value.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Will research more what's special about `rels`

Comment: Actually sorry - this was my original answer to my own question, however I get a message that binding relationships is deprecated and to use WITH *, relationships(p) instead.

Comment: That works - thank you! Does `(p)[1..]` work because for each array in relationships(p) the first relationship is the type `:RELA`?

Comment: Yes. That query generates a `p` whose first relationship is always of type `RELA`.